# How to switch to an other page in a function with arguments/datas?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm looking for a method that allow me to switch from a page another one in a function called by a button right after an api request.

In my case, i want to do an authentication form, so when i click on a button, i call a functon that take the informations on the inputs and send it to an api, then I receive the response and if it's successful i want to switch on an other page with user's datas received in the response of the request

There is my code in the login form:

[image: Login's Form]

And this is the code of the router (because I've already setup one to try something):
[image: Router's Code]

Comment: In a component you can use [useHistory](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/usehistory) hook with method `push` or you can you render a [Redirect](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Redirect). With the `Redirect` component you can use the `to` prop as an object which allows specifying state. With history the `push` can take state as well. In the receiving component you can access the passed state from [useLocation](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/uselocation). The example on [Redirects](https://reactrouter.com/web/example/auth-workflow) covers all of this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [history](https://www.npmjs.com/package/history) library. So when the user's data was received you can change the page and pass the data via `history.push('/Dashboard', { data })`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `history.push` and send data along it.

```
    if(data.success){
        this.props.history.push({
          pathname: '/dashboard',
          state: { 
            email: response.data.email,
            password: response.data.password}
        })
      }
```

OR you can use `LINK` for it.

```
<Link to={{
      pathname: '/template',
      state: { 
        email: response.data.email,
        password: response.data.password
  }    }
    }}> Button </Link>
```

and then access it on the other component linke this:

```
this.props.location.state.email;
this.props.location.state.password;
```